# how to write typescript definition file for this javascript library?

Tags: javascript, typescript, definition

I need call the following javascript:

```
var jslib = jslib || (function() {
var publicMethods = {
    encrypt: function (algorithm, keyHandle, buffer) {
        // implementation
    }
};

return publicMethods;
})();
```

I am new to typescript, can you please share what the typescript definition will look like for the javascript above and invoke pattern?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the following directory structure

```
├── lib
│   ├── jslib.d.ts
│   └── jslib.js
├── src
    └── t.ts
```

jslib.js

```
var jslib = jslib || (function () {
  var publicMethods = {
    encript: function () {
      return
    }
  };

  return publicMethods;
})();

module.exports = jslib;
```

jslib.d.ts

```
declare namespace jslib {
  function encript(): void;
}

export = jslib;
```

t.ts

```
import jslib = require('../lib/jslib');

jslib.encript();
```

Check with  `node_modules/.bin/tsc --traceResolution`

```
======== Resolving module '../lib/jslib' from '/home/zjk/dev/webnote/ts1/src/t.ts'. ========
Explicitly specified module resolution kind: 'NodeJs'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location '/home/zjk/dev/webnote/ts1/lib/jslib'.
File '/home/zjk/dev/webnote/ts1/lib/jslib.ts' does not exist.
File '/home/zjk/dev/webnote/ts1/lib/jslib.tsx' does not exist.
File '/home/zjk/dev/webnote/ts1/lib/jslib.d.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
Resolving real path for '/home/zjk/dev/webnote/ts1/lib/jslib.d.ts', result '/home/zjk/dev/webnote/ts1/lib/jslib.d.ts'
======== Module name '../lib/jslib' was successfully resolved to '/home/zjk/dev/webnote/ts1/lib/jslib.d.ts'. ========
```

It is crucial to put `jslib.js` and `jslib.d.ts` in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks zjk. I have two dumb questions  1) in javascript,how to understand var jslib = jslib || function(), I do not understand why jslib needs show up again after "="   2) in your answer, what does const jslib mean?   sorry, I am green to both scripts..

Comment: @SkyLine.  Good questions! I'm no expert. I'll update in my answer

Comment: I have not tried my answer. I'll expand it later. As for `var jslib = jslib || function()`, it can prevent redefine the whole jslib if it is already defined.

Comment: Thanks @zjk.  i am looking forward your update then :)

Comment: @SkyLine I must admit that I do not understand this issue well enough to answer this question.  Sorry for the delay.